# How to convert video to required codec?

Tags: video, codec

I am trying to convert mp4 videos to match the codec requirement of

Codec: XVID as per the attached picture. 
Can anyone advise how or what tool can be used?
[screenshot http://xomf.com/wkvgv](http://xomf.com/wkvgv)

http://xomf.com/wkvgv

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ffmpeg to perform this conversion. Grab the 32-bit static build from [here](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/).

And run the following command from the command prompt:

```
ffmpeg -i "c:\path\to\input.avi" -c:v libxvid -vtag xvid -qscale:v 3 -c:a libmp3lame -qscale:a 4 output.avi
```

You can experiment with the value of qscale:v to get the quality or file size that you need. Values from 1 to 31 are accepted, with 1 being best quality (and largest file size) and 31 being worst quality and smallest file size.